# I dont understand it. How arent there any 2-cycles in the Klein Bottle?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra

> As we found for the torus, if we triangulate the Klein bottle by dividing Fig. 43.2 into triangles, every $1$-cycle is homologous to a cycle of the form
> $$ra+sb$$
> for $r$ and $s$ integers. If a $2$-chain is to have a boundary containing just $a$ and $b$, again, all the triangles oriented counterclockwise must appear with the same coefficient so that the inner edges will cancel each other. In the case of the torus, the boundary of such a $2$-chain was $0$. Here, however, it is $k(2a)$, where $k$ is the number of times each triangle appears. Thus $H_1(X)$ is an abelian group with generators the homology classes of $a$ and $b$ and the relations $a+b=b+a$ and $2a=0$. Therefore,
> $$H_1(X)\simeq\mathbb Z_2×\mathbb Z,$$
> a group with torsion coefficient $2$ and Betti number $1$. Our argument above regarding $2$-chains shows that there are no $2$-cycles this time, so
> $$H_2(X)=0.$$

I dont really get how does the $H_1(X)$ argument explain the non-existance of $2$-cycles in the Klein Bottle. Maybe it isnt clear enough or Im just looking at it from the wrong angle. If someone could give me an alternative explanation to the one in the image I would appreciate it

Thanks

Comment: It seems like a rather straightforward explanation and I would not like to guess which part of it you did not understand. It would greatly help if you could rewrite your post so as to walk us through the explanation, indicating how your understanding of it breaks down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\sigma$ be a $2$-cycle. We have that $\partial \sigma = 0a + 0b$, so we can apply the prior argument to conclude that $\partial \sigma = k(2a) = 0$. Thus $k=0$. Can we use this to conclude that $\sigma = 0$?

Comment: Why does $k$ need to be $0$? $2a$ is already $0$

Comment: @BALBINOSOBREVIELAJIMÉNEZ: $\sigma$ is a cycle if $\partial \sigma = 0$ AS A chain, NOT as an element of homology, which is a stricter condition. Note that $\partial: C_{2} \to C_{1}$ NOT $\partial: C_{2} \to H_{1}$.

Comment: Ohhh, now it all clicks. Thanks, very helpful.